# how to count index of **pointer

Tags: c

I'm  beginner in c programming  and I want to use list of addresses in 
hostent structure but I  can't count how  many addresses are there
 my code is

```
int main (int argc,  char *argv[])
{
  int i;
  struct hostent  *host_info;
  struct in_addr *address;
  if(argc <2)
    {
      printf("USAGE: %s <hostname>\n",argv[0]);
      exit(1);
    }
  host_info=gethostbyname(argv[1]);
  if(host_info==NULL)
    {
      printf("couldn't lookup %s\n",argv[1]);

    }
  else
    {
      for(i=0;i<??????????;i++){
      address=(struct in_addr *)(host_info ->h_addr_list[i]);
      printf("%s  has address %s\n",argv[1],inet_ntoa(*address));
      }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The host_addr structure doesn't contain a length for the address list.  Instead, the last entry in the address list is 0 (NULL).  So loop while `host_info->h_addr_list[i] != 0`

Answer (score 0):

You can make the calling like this,

```
 while(host_info ->h_addr_list[i]  != NULL){
  address=(struct in_addr *)(host_info ->h_addr_list[i]);
  printf("%s  has address %s\n",argv[1],inet_ntoa(*address));
  }
```